# Jenkins pipeline fails and the following error is thrown

Tags: maven, jenkins, pom.xml, maven-surefire-plugin

Hello I'm trying to run a test case using maven in build step and I keep running into the following error message
ERROR: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.20.1:test
Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.20.1:test failed.: Null Pointer Exception

Steps to fix:
I've tried to update the surefire plugin but still keep getting the same error message with the same surefire plugin version number.
I've also tried to run without surefire but to no avail

Any suggestions on how to fix this are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Doesthe mvn build work locally?